# Adding anchor points offset from intersections automatically in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, anchor-point

I'm a stained glass artist using Illustrator to create patterns and cutting templates. I'm always looking for ways to simplify and automate things.

My designs are ultimately just a series of paths crossing each other on a simple Illustrator artboard. [Here's a zoomed in example of an intersection of two paths where 4 pieces of glass would meet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbEFX.jpg)

I'd like to automatically have the paths be a different stroke width or color a specific distance (say for example, 2mm) leading up to the intersection along each path, to speed up measuring the lengths of joining material that happens at these intersections.
[I know that I can do this manually by creating a 2mm circle centered at the intersection, using Pathfinder->Outline, and deleting the parts I don't need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjm9T.jpg). This then lets me control and [stroke or color the lines leading up to the intersection, as needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlMsI.jpg).

For small designs, this workflow is fine. For large designs (100s of intersections), this would be pretty tedious, and not worth the effort. Is there any way to automate this a bit using the path offsetting tools or scripts or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option (without scripting) is to add another stroke to your paths in the Appearance Panel (Window> Appearance). Put this stroke under the original stroke and make it wider than the original stroke to suit the particular offset proportions you need. I made the added stroke white and set just that strokes blend mode to difference so that it is only visible where the strokes overlap.

[image]

In the appearance Panels top right drop down menu uncheck "New Art Has Basic Appearance" so that all your new lines will have this appearance.

You can also save this as a Graphic Style (Window> Graphic Styles) for future use.

NOTE- This will not give you added anchor points but merely a visual cutting reference. If what you need is actual anchor points at these intersections it would require expanding and shapebuilder or pathfinder.

Comment: Flatten teansparency would be faster since it would react to the transparency.

Comment: @ joojaa- excellent !

Comment: @Kyle, thanks, I think this will do the trick nicely! The anchor points aren't strictly necessary for this, just the visual cue.

Comment: @joojaa I'm not familiar with the flatten transparency operation. How would I use that to get the same effect?